# Testing ValidationAttribute that overrides IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, validationattribute

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around testing my custom validation attribute. As the method signature is `protected` when I invoke the `IsValid` method in my unit test, I can't pass in a `Mock<ValidationContext>` object, it's calling the base `virtual bool IsValid(object value)` instead.

**ValidationAttribute**

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
    var otherPropertyValue = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

    if (value != null)
    {
        if (otherPropertyValue == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(this.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

**Test**

```
[Test]
public void Should_BeValid_WhenPropertyIsNullAndOtherPropertyIsNull()
{
    var attribute = new OptionalIfAttribute("test");
    var result = attribute.IsValid(null);

    Assert.That(result, Is.True);
}
```

If I'm unable to pass in a mocked validation context, then how can I test this class properly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [`Validator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator(v=vs.110).aspx) class to perform the validation manually without having to mock anything. There is a brief article on it [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx). I would probably do something like

```
[Test]
public void Should_BeValid_WhenPropertyIsNullAndOtherPropertyIsNull()
{
    var target = new ValidationTarget();
    var context = new ValidationContext(target);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(target, context, results, true);

    Assert.That(isValid, Is.True);
}

private class ValidationTarget
{
    public string X { get; set; }

    [OptionalIf(nameof(X))]
    public string OptionalIfX { get; set; }
}
```

You could optionally make assertions on `results`.

Comment: This is what I in fact ended up doing, but forgot to put the answer here.

Comment: You should set the validateAllProperties arg in Validator.TryValidateObject, or else it does not check the properies,   var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(target, context, results, true);

Comment: Thanks @FeiyuZhou, without validateAllProperties = true it does not validate my custom attribute and return IsValid = true every time.